# How to check if the string contains a number in js without regular expressions?

Tags: javascript

How to check if the string contains a number in javascript  without regular expressions ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether a string contains a substring in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-to-check-whether-a-string-contains-a-substring-in-javascript)

Comment: What is your reasoning for not wanting to use a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
str.indexOf(number.toString()) > -1
```

Comment: also you don't need toString()

Answer (score -1):

You can check as follows:

```js
if (mystring.indexOf(21) >= 0){
    // Contains number 21
}
```